# Woocommerce can't update order review after change cart totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have change the cart totals on Woocommerce using the following code and now I have problems with the checkout page specifically the update_order_review function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10, 1);
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) 
{

    if (is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach($cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item )
    {
        ## Price calculation ##
        $price = $cart_item['data']->price*$cart_item['adult_add_on'] + $cart_item['data']->price*$cart_item['child_add_on'] + $cart_item['data']->price*0.75*$cart_item['infant_add_on'];

        ## Set the price with WooCommerce compatibility ##
        if(version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' )) 
        {
            $cart_item['data']->price = $price; // Before WC 3.0
        } 
        else 
        {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price ); // WC 3.0+
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I need one more step to change some of the code, because when I remove the function, woocommerce can update the order review.

I am getting `wc_ajax=update_order_review 502 (Bad Gateway)`

Can anybody help me resolve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get a server error, because this code is not cautious enough:

```
$price = $cart_item['data']->price*$cart_item['adult_add_on'] + $cart_item['data']->price*$cart_item['child_add_on'] + $cart_item['data']->price*0.75*$cart_item['infant_add_on'];
```

Maybe try first to make sure the array has you custom fields:

```
if ( !empty($cart_item['adult_add_on']) && !empty($cart_item['child_add_on'])  && !empty($cart_item['infant_add_on']) ) {

$price = $cart_item['data']->price*$cart_item['adult_add_on'] + $cart_item['data']->price*$cart_item['child_add_on'] + $cart_item['data']->price*0.75*$cart_item['infant_add_on'];

}
```

Comment: Yeah the price is being calculated before the checkout and setted on cart price, the used filter is woocommerce_before_calculate_totals, so it shouldn't affect.

Comment: It actually runs every time the order review is being updated .

Comment: (even after the checkout fully loaded)

Comment: I tried adding the if before the price calculation but no error is throw.